# Add data from a csv to a SharePoint online library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-workflow

I have a document library called "TestLib" with 2 custom fields named "EmpName" & "EmpCity". I have 1000 records available in a .csv form with their appropriate document files locally.

I need to upload the document along with the custom fields from a csv file similar to how an export works.

On export of document library to excel gives the following:

```
ID | Name |  Modified     |  Modified By | EmpName | EmpCity | ItemType | Path 
1    FZ    5/18/2016 10:05      KZ         TestEmp   Pune      Item      sites/...
```

I have tried the following:-

www.codeproject.com/Articles/134054/Restoring-Two-Way-Synchronization-on-SharePoint-Lo

Any help shall be greatly appreciated!

Comment: After a lot of research found a lot of articles to sync sharepoint library using business one drive, but in my case I have some custom columns which I need to update as well along with the documents.

Comment: You should write a c# console application using CSOM that will read the csv line per line and insert the data line per line into the SharePoint list

Comment: That's also possible via JavaScript, I tried that and it does work as well. Also if don't like to code you can try to use excel

Comment: Thanks Nils, Well how can i use excel to achieve the same? Please note its a document library with custom columns.

Comment: I don't know, if this is possible in your case, but you can load your csv file inside excel and make a version of it (copy) where the columns resemble those of your sharepoint list. Then open your doc lib in quick edit mode and just paste the excel rows over to sharepoint. This is not very "elegant" but in some cases its faster than coding. Here is a link to demonstrate the process: http://www.boostsolutions.com/blog/things-to-know-about-sharepoint-2013-quick-edit-part-1/

Comment: I have 2000 records to be added, I cant do it manually using quick edit. Can you suggest another way / alternate script using csom (Javascript)?